# How to use conditional CSS In CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I have to translate this code:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7-style.css" />    <![endif]-->
```

for CakePHP. At the moment I'm using `$this->Html->css('fileName')` in the view file and in the default.ctp I do `echo $this->fetch('css');`

But what do to when i must to use a conditional css expression like above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want conditionals set inside a view file (as in not in a layout), you can do:

```
// in your view file
$this->Html->css('file', null, array('block' => 'ie_conditional_css'));

// in layout
<?php if ($ieConditionalCss = $this->fetch('ie_conditional_css')): ?
<!--[if lt IE 8]><?php echo $ieConditionalCss ; ?><![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just put the comments around your PHP, like this:

`<!--[if lt IE 8]><?php echo $html->css('filename') ?><![endif]-->`

Comment: hmm are you sure? because the problem should be if i use $this->Html->css('file') inside a view. The default.ctp will prints all the css files doing $this->fetch('css') but if i do something like that i must to put it in the layout..... no?

Comment: Yes, you need to put this into the `<head>` of your layout any maybe add the `'inline'=>true` option to make it an extra link.